# Application uploaded to Apache Livy fails if not compiled with all dependencies jars

Tags: java, apache-spark, livy

I'm submitting a batch Job, the Pi Job, with a curl command to Livy , but it fails because the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.livy.Job`. If I compile my jar with all the dependencies inside the jar file then it works.

Why do I need to do that? I'm executing it on Livy, at least I expect Livy have it's owns dependencies available.

Answer (score 0):

Livy simulate spark submit in nature use SparkLauncher,
so you jar should be fatJar,include all dependency.

Comment: Could you add more explanation ? Thanks.